# Не могу понять как написать метод insert для класса HashTable

Tags: python

Я не могу понять как написать метод insert.

Вот код, который пока что готов:

```
class HashTable:

def __init__(self):
    # ограничение на 4 слота 
    self._content = [[], [], [], []]


def get_hash(self, key):
   if key == '':

      return 3

   return ord(key[0]) * len(key)

# нужно использовать self.get_hash() но не знаю как именно лучше

def insert(self, key, value):
    # хэш-функция
    hash_key = hash(key) % len(self._content)
    key_exists = False
    bucket = self._content[hash_key]
    for i, kv in enumerate(bucket):
        k, v = kv
        if key == k:
            key_exists = True
            break
    if key_exists:
        bucket[i] = (key, value)
    else:
        bucket.append((key, value))


Примерно как должно работать:
h = HashTable()
h.insert('a', 'b')
print(h)
0: []
1: [('a', 'b')]
2: []
3: []

h.insert('apple', 'bee')
0: []
1: [('a', 'b'), ('apple', 'bee')]
2: []
3: []

h.insert('apple', 'juice')
0: []
1: [('a', 'b'), ('apple', 'juice')]
2: []
3: []
```

Буду признателен за любую помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вычисление этого ключа

```
hash_key = hash(key) % len(self._content)
```

происходит неверно. Нужно просто изменить на

```
hash_key = self.get_hash(key) % len(self._content)
```

Comment: Ой, даже не заметил ! Спасибо большое